# Unity 2D: Destroy object with dynamic collider after exiting object with static collider

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection

I'm using the Unity5 game engine and am programming a 2D shooter in bird's eye view.

I have a static Box Collider 2D which covers the entire game area.

[image]

It has "Is Trigger" checked and contains a very simple script which should destroy every object that exits it.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class DestroyByBoundary : MonoBehaviour {
     void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
         Debug.Log ("OnTriggerExit");
         Destroy (other.gameObject);
     }
 }
```

The player character shoots bullets which have a dynamic Circle Collider 2D.

[image]

However, the bullets are never destroyed when they leave the game area and just fly on indefinitely. The debug statement never gets executed either, of course. I have tried the same thing with OnTriggerEnter, which yields the same result.

If any more information should be needed, I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing 2D & 3D physics. Try using `OnTriggerExit2D` and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) has pointed out in a comment, I was using 3D objects and methods in a 2D environment.

I had to change the parameter of the script to a `Collider2D` object and use the `OnTriggerExit2D` method.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class DestroyByBoundary : MonoBehaviour {
     void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
         Destroy (other.gameObject);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer, for future readers.